# What is the best threading approach to this issue in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have about 30 calculations that need to be done on a few thousand data points. The calculations are done in a 3rd party library.
Each call can be done in parallel so I was thinking of putting the call into several threads.

The issue that I get is how to properly terminate the calls if need be. Since I don't have access to the lib which is where most of the time is, I can't exit the thread in a nice manner.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably just have to kill them.

Comment: Why terminate the calls?  If the calculation isn't working at that moment, do you expect it to work if you try it again later?

Comment: The user may change the inputs which is why I would need to kill it.

Answer (score 4):

If the 3rd party library is a managed library, or spends most CPU time in managed code, you can call it from a separate appdomain and nuke the whole appdomain when you need to terminate calculations. If the calculations are mainly in unmanaged code, run the calculations as a separate process and nuke the whole process. Any other approaches are subtly dangerous and therefore unadvisable.